# NSData absurd Length error

Tags: ios, ios4, gdb, nsdata

I am getting this error

```
*** -[NSConcreteData initWithBytes:length:copy:freeWhenDone:bytesAreVM:]: absurd length: 4294967283, maximum size: 2147483648 bytes
```

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you passed a negative number (-13) as argument to `length`. Make sure your length calculations are correct.